# Symfony2 Service Class. Function Call

Tags: php, symfony

I have a service like this :

```
  services:
    prodacom_authentication.encode:
      class: Prodacom\AuthenticationBundle\Service\Encode
      arguments: ["@security.context"]
```

the service function i want to call in a controller:

```
public function encodePassword() {
    $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
    $user = new Prodacom\MainBundle\Entity\PdbUser();

    $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
    $password = $encoder->encodePassword('ryanpass', $user->getSalt());
    var_dump($password);
    $user->setPassword($password);
}
```

i want to call the function encodePassword in the authenticationController.php.

```
    $this->get('prodacom_authentication.encode')->encodePassword();
```

but i keep getting this error :

```
    Attempted to call method "get" on class "Prodacom\AuthenticationBundle\Service\Encode" in C:\htdocs\domeinbeheer\src\Prodacom\AuthenticationBundle\Service\Encode.php line 12.
```

any ideas ???

Comment: If You want to use `->get('')` in Your service You have to pass `container` service to It.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the second line in your method, where you call: `$this->get('security.encoder_factory')`

Within your service, the method `get()` is not defined if you have not implemented it yourself. Your controller has it, because it extends a class called `ContainerAware`, that implements this method.

You can now either inject the complete dependency-container (not recommended) or just inject the services you need into your service. Here's a list of different ways you can use to inject services into your service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html

I saw you're already familiar with constructor-injection ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a service in another one, you have to use dependency injection.

`$this->get()` is available in a controller context only.

You'll find a full example  in official documentation : 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html

***Note*** : You have to pass each service or parameters you need in injection. 
Inject the container to call others services can seems more easy, but is a bad practice.